# Kubernetes - container communication within a pod using names instead of 'localhost'?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

From the kubernetes [docs](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/pods/):

> The applications in a pod all use the same network namespace (same IP and port space), and can thus “*find*” each other and communicate using localhost.

*Is it possible to use some container specific names instead of `locahost`?*

For example, with `docker-compose up`, you use *name of the service* to communicate. [[docs]](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

So, if my **docker-compose.yml** file is

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  srv:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Then I access `srv` from within `web` by calling `http://srv:3000/`, **not** `http://localhost:3000`

How can I achieve the same behaviour in kubernetes? Any way to specify what name to use in pods' yaml configuration?

Answer (score 14):

`localhost` is just a name for the network loopback device (usually `127.0.0.1` for IPv4 and `::1` for IPv6). This is usually specified in your `/etc/hosts` file.

A pod has its own IP, so each container inside shares that IP. If these containers should be independent (i.e. don't need to be collocated), they should each be in their own pod. Then, you can define a [service](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#defining-a-service) for each that allows DNS lookups as either "$SERVICENAME" from pods in the same namespace, or "$SERVICENAME.$NAMESPACE" from pods in different namespaces.

Comment: but I can't change so the `/etc/hosts` of a pod manually since hosts can come and go. Also since the containers belong together I can't make them a service. Any way around here?

Answer (score 6):

`docker-compose` deploys individual containers, linking them together so they know each other's name and IP.

a `Pod` in Kubernetes is similar, but this is not the purpose of a Pod to hold multiple external services and link them together.

A Pod is for containers that must be running on the same host, and interact among themselves only. The containers communicate internally via localhost.

Most `Pods` are in fact a single container.

A `Pod` communicates with the outside using `Services`. In essence a Pod appears as if it was just one container.

under the hood, a Pod is at least 2 containers: the `pause` container manages the IP of the Pod, and then your attached container. This allows your container to crash, restart, and be relinked in the Pod without changing IP, allowing to manage container crashes without involving the scheduler, and making sure the Pod stays on a single node during its lifetime, so restart is fast.

If containers we rescheduled each time they crash, they would potentially end up on a different host, routing would have to be updated etc...

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Containers running inside a pod, shares pod's IP and Port space. The communication between the containers will happen through localhost by default. To communicate between the containers using the name(like DNS), the containers should run in the independent POD and expose it as a service to rest of application world.