# How to communicate between 2 pods on the same node in Kubernetes (using Python)?

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service

I've read like a dozen tutorials like [these](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) and many answers like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46535057/how-do-pods-on-the-same-node-communicate-with-each-other) but they couldn't help me. I have a service like

- if I have this said service, what do I need to do/use to send the files?

For clarification: I have 2 pods **A** and **B** (both have 1 container each with standard Python Docker images) and wish to send files back and forth. So if I have the service, I have the port(s) and then I can use the combination of IP:port to send the files e.g. by creating a (TCP) server and a client Python? Or is there a "more Kubernetes-like" way to do this?

The service I created using Python:

```
def create_service(core_v1_api):
    body = client.V1Service(
        api_version="v1",
        kind="Service",
        metadata=client.V1ObjectMeta(
            name="banking-svc"
        ),

        spec=kube_setup.client.V1ServiceSpec(
            selector={"app": "my_app"},
            type="ClusterIP",
            ports=[client.V1ServicePort(
                port=6666,
                target_port=6666,
                protocol="TCP"
            )]
        )
    )
    core_v1_api.create_namespaced_service(namespace="default", body =body)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I would suggest reading [the official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/), which is a reasonably good introduction to the idea of a service in kubernetes.

> I have only roughly idea what to put into this service file (or these service files?)

A service is just a pointer to one (or more) network services provided by your pods.

For example, if you have a pod running Postgres on port 5432, you might create a service named "database" that will map connections to `database:5432` to port 5432 on your pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: database
spec:
  selector:
    app: postgres
  ports:
    - name: postgres
      port: 5432
```

There are two main parts to `service.spec`:

- `selector` identifies the pod or pods that actually provide the
  service. Here, we're saying that this service will round-robin among
  any pods with label `app` equal to `postgres`.
- `ports` describes the ports on which we listen and the correspond
  port in the pod. Here, we're mapping port `5432` to a port named
  `postgres` in matching pods. That assumes you've set up your ports
  with names, like this:

  ```
  ...
  ports:
    - name: postgres
      containerPort: 5432
  ...
  ```

  If you haven't assigned names to your ports, you can use
  `targetPort` instead in your service:

  ```
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    name: database
  spec:
    selector:
      app: postgres
    ports:
      - targetPort: 5432
        port: 5432
  ```

With the above service in place, pods in the same namespace can connect to the host `database` on port `5432` in order to interact with Postgres.

> if I have this said service, what do I need to do/use to send the files?

If you have two pods (let's call them `pod1` and `pod2`), and you want each pod to initiate connections to the other pod, create two services, one with a selector that matches `pod1` and the other with a selector that matches `pod2`.

The name you give your service is the hostname to which you will connect from inside a pod.

Comment: Ok, the first half of your answer answers my first question but... Then what? If I have the 2 services, what do I do?

Comment: I tried to answer that in the second part of my answer. If you've created two Services, then you have two hostnames. To connect to a pod, use the name of the service that selects the pod in its `selector` block. If you'd like to update your question to show specifics (e.g., here are my two pod manifests, and here are the specific commands/code I want to run), I'd be happy to add some details.