# NATS Service inside multiple image Kubernetes Pod

Tags: kubernetes, k3s, nats.io

I am trying to consolidate several services which were previously run as different pods in Kuberentes, with the hope of reducing system latency. Our system involves communication between several different pods which were often on different nodes in our cluster - due to the specific element of the deployment (most notably the large size of the data sent between the programs), communication between programs on different nodes is the primary source of latency in our system.

One of the components is NATS, which handles the communication between the different services. I naively tried to include the NATS image in the deployment like so:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: vei-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: camera-system
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: camera-system
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: application
          image: image1:latest
        - name: application2
          image: image2:latest
        - name: application3
          image: image3:latest
        - name: nats
          image: nats
```

Application 1 is a Golang program that was connects to NATs using the standard library, and the code:

```
//start a new connection with NATS
var nc, err = nats.Connect("nats://nats:4222")
if err != nil {
        panic(err)
}
defer nc.Close()
```

However, when doing so, the systems refuse to connect to NATs, throwing the error `panic: dial tcp: lookup nats on 10.43.0.10:53: no such host` , though according to the logs, NATs is working correctly. What am I missing in order to make this deployment operable?

Comment: Stuffing multiple unrelated containers into the same Pod isn't usually a best practice.  (If nothing else, this makes it hard to scale the Deployment to multiple replicas, and makes it hard to effectively use all of the hosts in your cluster.)  Do you have some specific evidence that this is solving a real performance problem?  When you say "it refuses to connect", can you show the actual code that's trying to make the connection and the actual error message?

Comment: I hope that I have answered the questions to your satisfaction @DavidMaze

Comment: If you're trying to connect to a host name `nats`, that will refer to a separate Service, presumably matching a separate Deployment.

Comment: The question that I guess I am trying to ask is how to connect to a host in the same deployment.

Comment: Are you trying to [Kubernetes - container communication within a pod using names instead of 'localhost'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38383779/kubernetes-container-communication-within-a-pod-using-names-instead-of-localh)

Comment: I am trying to connect to another container in a deployment